# select records from data frame using a range as a variable

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, subset

I have a data frame "table" that has a column with name "ID". The values of "ID" go from 1 to 100. The data frame also has a column with name "weight".

I have a function "calc_mean" that has a variable to select the "ID":

```
calc_mean <- function(id=1:100)
```

when I call my function, I want to be able to take a subset of this "ID", for example:

```
calc_mean(30:35)
```

this would have to calculate the mean of my column "weight" when writing the following code in my function:

```
mean(table$weight[,id])
```

but I get the following error:

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(table$weight[, id]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

What is wrong?

Alternatively, I would be happy if I could make a subset of this data frame "table" into another data frame called "table2" with only the ID's that interest me. I would think of the following code then:

```
for(i in id){
table2 <- table[table$ID == i,]
}
```

followed by:

```
mean(table2$weight)
```

however, this gives me the error:

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(table2$weight) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

What is wrong here?

=============================================================================

Sorry, I wanted to hide my real code first for certain reasons but will now show the real code:

```
pollutantmean <- function(dummy_dir, pollutant, id = 1:332) {
pollutant <- c("sulfate", "nitrate")
directory <- "C:\\Users\\kieken\\Dropbox\\science\\R programming\\specdata"
setwd(directory)
files <- list.files(directory)
data.list <- lapply(files, read.csv)
data.cat <- do.call(rbind, data.list)
good <- complete.cases(data.cat)
data.clean <- data.cat[good,]

data.ID <- subset(data.clean, ID %in% id)
mean(data.ID[,pollutant])

}
pollutantmean("specdata", "nitrate", 70:72)
```

This code is giving me the following error:

[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data.ID[, pollutant]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Comment: I noticed you didn't post the function.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. It may be impossible to diagnose your problem if you don't post what we'd need to recreate your problem.

Comment: I removed the following code and it worked now: pollutant <- c("sulfate", "nitrate")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would have to calculate the mean of my column "weight" when writing the following code in my function:

```
mean(table$weight[,id])
```

The comma here doesn't make sense. `table$weight` is a vector, which means it has only one dimension, not two. Hence you should use `mean(table$weight[id])`.

```
for(i in id){ table2 <- table[table$ID == i,] }
```

followed by:

```
mean(table2$weight)
```

Notice that each time you loop inside the `for` function, you are replacing `table2` by another one with a different row from `table`. To create a subset you can either use

```
table2 <- table[id,]
```

or

```
table2 <- subset(table, ID %in% id)
```

Comment: I still encounter problems: actually in stead of "weight", I also had a variable "colum" that I call in my function and that I define as follows: colum <- c("weight", "age"). So, If I try your mean(table2$weight), it works but when I replace it by mean(table2[,colum]), I get the following error: "[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(table2[, colum]) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA"

Comment: mean(table2[,colum] is the same as mean(table2[,c("weight","age")]. You need to decide which column you are using to compute the mean. Besides, I don't understand why inside your function you redefine your inputs (eg directory and pollutant), shouldn't you compute the mean based on the inputs given by the user? And please read the instructions to asking a question on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: about the directory: I am completely confused. It seems that they only want to give as input for the directory "specdata" while this is only the last part of the directory. But the command needs to have the whole path no? How do you people usually do this? In which directory do you put your R and in which directory do you put your own programs? And what if you want to work on different computers?

Comment: Chris, please refrain from changing the subject too much. Your question has been solved, apparently (and you haven't checked any answer as the one you were looking for). I suggest you to create another question and explain in details what you're having trouble with, what your code looks like and what have you tried but did not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to calculate the mean "weight" for a subset of "id", then you can just use `with`. The following code calculates the mean weight in a given range of "id"

```
# data example
table <- data.frame(id=1:100, weight=runif(100,60,95))

with(table, mean(weight[id %in% 30:35]))
```

Comment: but by saying 30:35, you hardcode the value while it should be a variable ... shouldn't it be with(table, mean(weight[ID %in% id])) ??? but even that gave errors ...